# Bad word wrap styling for company name under Job Recommendations on user activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design

I noticed for listed job postings if the company name is too long it reaches into the next box.

[image]

I was able to fix it by setting `max-width: 100%` on the company name, but if you do that, I'd recommend setting `margin-top: auto` on the REMOTE element as well

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have updated the UI on both the activity and dev story pages. This UI has been updated to reflect the UI on the actual [/jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) page. Not only does this fix the bug that you have logged, but it is an attempt to create a more consistent experience and easier browsing.

[image: Screenshot of new job recommendation UI]

Thanks for bringing this issue to our attention and let me know if you have any questions :)